# How to return Observable<array[]> of method?

Tags: angular, return, observable

I have this code, T'm trying to fetch list of users from the database with an http get request, but it looks like the method gives me the error that the function doesn't return a value, i don't understand why

CODE:

```
listFriends(): Observable<ParticipantResponse[]>{
        this.serviceChat.list_users().subscribe((res)=>{
              console.log(res)
              res.data.forEach(user => {
              MyAdapter.userAdd={};
              MyAdapter.userAdd.id=user.id;
              MyAdapter.userAdd.avatar=user.avatar;
              MyAdapter.userAdd.status=user.status;
              MyAdapter.userAdd.participantType=0;
              MyAdapter.userAdd.displayName=user.displayName;
              MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.push(MyAdapter.userAdd)              
            });        
          console.log(MyAdapter.mockedParticipants)
       return of(MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.map(users=> {
        console.log(users)
        let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
  
         participantResponse.participant = users;
         participantResponse.metadata = {
           totalUnreadMessages: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        }
        console.log(participantResponse)
         return participantResponse;
      }));
          }),
          error =>{
            let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
            console.log(error)
            return participantResponse
          }; 
          setTimeout(() => {
            return of(MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.map(utente => {
              console.log(utente)
              let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
        
               participantResponse.participant = utente;
               participantResponse.metadata = {
                 totalUnreadMessages: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
              }
              console.log(participantResponse)
               return participantResponse; 
              }));     
          }, 10000);   
     }
```

Comment: You are subscribing inside a function that you expect to return an observable, Consider refactoring your code

Comment: you are not specifying the return for the function that it is giving undefined and you might want to think about refactoring the code

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct implementation -

```
   listFriends(): Observable<ParticipantResponse[]>{
          return  this.serviceChat.list_users().pipe(map(res => {
            console.log(res)
                  res.data.forEach(user => {
                  MyAdapter.userAdd={};
                  MyAdapter.userAdd.id=user.id;
                  MyAdapter.userAdd.avatar=user.avatar;
                  MyAdapter.userAdd.status=user.status;
                  MyAdapter.userAdd.participantType=0;
                  MyAdapter.userAdd.displayName=user.displayName;
                  MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.push(MyAdapter.userAdd)              
                });        
              console.log(MyAdapter.mockedParticipants)
           return MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.map(users=> {
            console.log(users)
            let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
      
             participantResponse.participant = users;
             participantResponse.metadata = {
               totalUnreadMessages: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
            }
            console.log(participantResponse)
             return participantResponse;
          });
    }));
```

Now call this method like below -

```
listFriends().subscribe((res)=>{
              // res is your converted response above
          }),
          error =>{
            let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
            console.log(error)
            return participantResponse
          }; 
          setTimeout(() => {
            return of(MyAdapter.mockedParticipants.map(utente => {
              console.log(utente)
              let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();
        
               participantResponse.participant = utente;
               participantResponse.metadata = {
                 totalUnreadMessages: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
              }
              console.log(participantResponse)
               return participantResponse; 
              }));     
          }, 10000);   
     }
```

Comment: it's still not working, it keeps giving the same error "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

Comment: please add a `return` statement (first line in the function). See my updated answer.